# Determining the cause of a drools rule not firing

Tags: drools

With drools, is there a way to tell which part of a rule's "when" clause has failed that prevented the rule from firing? Or, barring that, to tell whether a rule did not fire because its conditions were not satisfied, or if it simply had a lower salience than a rule that halted the context?

Comment: Please add details to your question

Comment: If you log what rules fire, you can see if a higher salience rule might be halting the context.

Comment: you can add to your `kie-session` `DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener`: `kieSession.addEventListener(new DebugRuleRuntimeEventListener())`. Using this event listener you will see all the rule matched before activation (before firing ), firing all rules, then the result after fire (updates to facts among other things). I think this might help you identify what failed in matching your rule.